# CK editor: generate a event when Remove an element

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

As a part of project development, i have created a custom plugin as show in the image. I can add the object with class "placeholder".

`<span class="placeholder">Loop-ANS(Q2)</span>` .

Now when someone remove this from the editor i need to generate an event (call a function) so that i can mark this item has removed in some state. Could you please let me know what change i have to do for this ?

[screenshot of block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIdbL.png)

inline widget created from https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/tutorials/implementing-an-inline-widget.html#demo

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to check what was deleted is to add a `postFixer` to your plugin, preferably in `PlaceholderEditing` in the `init()` method

here is an example of how to use the postFixer, in this example i check if a list item has been removed

```
 this.editor.model.document.registerPostFixer((writer) => {
      const changes = this.editor.model.document.differ.getChanges();
      let didChange = false;
        for (const change of changes) {
          if (change.type === 'remove' && change.name === 'listItem') { 
           // custom logic to handle removal of list item
          }
        }
 })
```

Comment: @mosab ld , how we can pass a call back to ck-editor custom build ?

Comment: you can simply emit a custom event from your plugin.
you'll need to give your plugin a name 
```static get pluginName() {
    return 'PluginName';
  }```
then you'll need to import `import mix from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils/src/mix';`
and at the end of your plugin you need to mix
`mix(PluginName, EmitterMixin)`
now you will be able to use this.fire('event_name',values)
finally in the app you can do this
```this.editor.plugins
      .get('PluginName')
      .on('event_name', (evt, data) => {
        ...
      });```